React native accessiblity, increase item height by dp
My recent accessibility report shows I need to increase the dp of the touch target for one of my buttons to 48dp.
What is dp compared to pixels and how would know how many pixels to increase it by?

You basically have to use the following formula:
Pixels = DP × (Screen Density/160)

160 DPI is the baseline density (known as mdpi) used by Android.
Example:
fun dpToPx(context: Context, dp: Float): Float {
    val displayMetrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
    return dp * displayMetrics.density
}


If I have a button that I need to increase the height to 48dp how would I do that in react native?
